# Spring Security WebTestClient does not invoke OncePerRequestFilter when mocking JWT

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test

**Spring Boot Version: 2.4.2**

My application implements the following workflow:

1. An external client sends a HTTP request with a JWT token in the `Authorization` header.
2. The `JwtRequestfilter` extends the `OncePerRequestFilter` and extracts an information from the token.
3. This is passed to the `CustomUserDetailsService` which checks if a user with this information exists in the database.
4. Only if this check passes, the controller method is invoked with `@AuthenticationPrincipal` as parameter.

Now I'd like to test this controller method with Spring's `@WebTestClient` and mutate it with `mockJwt()`. I successfully managed to get the test request invoke the `CustomUserDetailsService` but there seem to be two problems:

1. The `JwtRequestFilter` is not invoked at all, i.e. the `loadUserById()` method is not called.
2. The user is not found by the `CustomUserDetailsService`. As I'd like to rely on the actual database, my idea was to mock the repository with Mockito but it always throws the `UsernameNotFoundException`.

This is the test implementation:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class UserControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @MockBean
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        webTestClient = MockMvcWebTestClient
                .bindToApplicationContext(this.context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails
    public void testIt() {
        final User user = createUser("foo@bar.com", "my-password");

        when(userRepo.findByEmail(anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));
        when(userRepo.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));

        webTestClient
                .mutateWith(mockJwt())
                .get()
                .uri("/services/user")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().is2xxSuccessful();
    }
}
```

---

Here are the relevant classes:

**JwtRequestFilter**

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final String BEARER_PREFIX = "Bearer ";

    private final HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public JwtRequestFilter(@Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver") HandlerExceptionResolver resolver, JwtService jwtService, CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.resolver = resolver;
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String token = parseTokenFromRequest(request);
            if (isNotBlank(token)) {
                String subject = jwtService.getSubject(token);
                if (isNotBlank(subject) && isNull(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication())) {
                    final MyaUserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserById(Long.valueOf(subject));
                    if (jwtService.validateToken(token, userDetails)) {
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
                    }
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (JwtException e) {
            resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, e);
        }
    }

    private String parseTokenFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (isNotBlank(token) && token.startsWith(BEARER_PREFIX)) {
            return token.substring(BEARER_PREFIX.length());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomUserDetailsService**

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final String USER_NOT_FOUND = "User not found";

    private final UserRepo userRepo;

    @Override
    public CustomUserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        final User user = userRepo.findByEmail(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(USER_NOT_FOUND));
        return buildUserDetails(user);
    }

    public CustomUserDetails loadUserById(Long id) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        final User user = userRepo.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(USER_NOT_FOUND));
        return buildUserDetails(user);
    }
}
```

**UserController**

```java
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<UserData> getUserData(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails userDetails) {
    try {
        final UserData userData = userService.getUser(userDetails.getId());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userData);
    } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
        log.error("User with id {} not found", userDetails.getId());
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using a custom spring security filter when there is already one in spring security? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture

Comment: several things, your webtest client if autowired will automatically be configured to be used against the started server. So your `@BeforeEach` is not needed https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-running-server

Comment: also we need to see your security configuration as it is not included here.